# Java LocaleDate or DateTime for checking if a car has to go for an occasional inspection

Tags: java

I need your help in my school task.
object car which gets an approval date .
After two years it have to go for an occasional inspection.
I need to check so compare the actual date with the approval date.
The checking with `approvalDate.plusYears(2).isAfter(actualDate)` 
is easy but how i can make it flexible, 
so that the method can used after the first check ,too ?

Comment: Why did you add the C# tag in a question about *Java*?

Comment: What you mean 'hat the method can used after the first check' ?

Comment: It still can be used after the first check. If you mean use it like use it for checking after another 2 years you probably should update approvalDate each time you prolong your validity period for car

Comment: How could i update it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void checkInspection(LocalDate firstApproval) {

    if(firstApproval.plusYears(2).isAfter(currentDate)){
        System.out.println("Your car have to go to an inspection");
        lastInspection = firstApproval.plusYears(2);
    }

}
```

With this method I can profe it for once but how i can make it flexible to use it more than once ???